# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{2})\cdot...\cdot(1+\frac{1}{2^n})$ exists and is between $(\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[4]{e}; \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{e})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I can prove the lower bound by just multiplying a few items from the sequence i.e. $\sqrt[4]{e} \approx 1.284$ and $\frac{5}{4}\cdot\frac{9}{8} \approx 1.4$, but I don't really know how to tackle the upper bound aside from it looking kinda like $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Use $1+x <e^x$ for all the terms past the first.

Comment: @A.S. This is nice ;)

Comment: And you can use $1+x> e^{x-x^2/2}$ to get much tighter a lower bound of $\frac 3 2\exp(\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {24})$.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm of your product is
$$
\sum_{n=k}^∞\ln(1+2^{-n})=\sum_{n=k}^∞\sum_{m=1}^∞(-1)^{m-1}\frac{2^{-mn}}m
=\sum_{m=1}^∞\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}m\sum_{n=k}^∞2^{-mn}
\\=\sum_{m=1}^∞\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}m\frac1{2^{(k-1)m}(2^{m}-1)}
$$
Thus  one finds with $k=2$ lower bounds from the partial sums with an even number of terms 
$$
\frac32\exp\Bigl(\frac12-\frac1{24}\Bigr),\;
\frac32\exp\Bigl(\frac12-\frac1{24}+\frac1{3·7·8}-\frac1{4·15·16}\Bigr),…
$$
and upper bounds from the partial sums with an odd number of terms
$$
\frac32\exp\Bigl(\frac12\Bigr),\;
\frac32\exp\Bigl(\frac12-\frac1{24}+\frac1{3·7·8}\Bigr),\;
\frac32\exp\Bigl(\frac12-\frac1{24}+\frac1{3·7·8}-\frac1{4·15·16}+\frac1{5·31·32}\Bigr),…
$$